# Count integer value and order by user

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So my `table` looks like this:

```
| id | user | points |
| 1  | Sam  |   1    |
| 2  | Sam  |   6    |
| 3  | Phil |   1    |
```

The query I am currently using is:

```
SELECT user,COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY user order by COUNT(*) DESC
```

This returns the current value:

```
Sam: 2
Phil: 1
```

It looks like it counts the number of rows, not the total points? How can I do this?

The correct return should be `Sam: 7`.

Comment: _Small Note_ phpMyAdmin is a tool written in PHP to assist in easier maintenace of a MySQL database. It is not a DBMS itself.

Comment: [Counting rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) and then [Adding column values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_sum) Both of which can be found in the user manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUM instead of COUNT

```
SELECT user, SUM(points) FROM table GROUP BY user
```